# How to omit "controllers." prefix in Play routes file?

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0

In Play 2.2, my `routes` file is full of the usual entries like:

```
GET   /                     controllers.Application.show(page = "home")
GET   /:page                controllers.Application.show(page)
GET   /blah                 controllers.Blah.blah()
```

Is there any way I can omit the `controllers.` prefix in this file?

Comment: Have you tried adding `routesImport += "controllers._"` to your project settings in `Build.scala`?

Comment: @Peter yes, but unfortunately I just get "Compilation Error: Controller method call expected" if I try and drop the `controllers` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like its currently possible. The `RoutesCompiler` is looking for an absolute method when parsing the routes file syntax:

from: [framework/src/routes-compiler/src/main/scala/play/router/RoutesCompiler.scala#L202](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/ab2ce0220a854d42d3320f16920d01fd171ccde9/framework/src/routes-compiler/src/main/scala/play/router/RoutesCompiler.scala#L202)

```scala
def absoluteMethod: Parser[List[String]] = namedError(javaIdent ~ "." ~ javaIdent ~ "." ~ rep1sep(javaIdent, ".") ^^ {
  case first ~ _ ~ second ~ _ ~ rest => first :: second :: rest
}, "Controller method call expected")
```